# Change asymmetric square matrix to the symmetric one

Tags: python, matlab, csv, matrix, symmetric

I have a matrix-form data stored in a CSV file, and it looks like this,

[image]

I want to make this 6 * 6 matrix be a symmetric matrix, like this,

[image]

How to use **python (or matlab)** to change an n by n matrix (square matrix) to a symmetric matrix？ Or are there **other tools** can do this？

Please give me any suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB, for an upper-triangular matrix `A` you can write

```
>> B = A' + triu(A,1)
```

where `triu(A,1)` extract the upper-triangular part without the diagonal - you do not want that to be doubled.